# Memory Leak - Socket or String related?

Tags: c++, string, sockets, memory-leaks

I have a simple function that allows me to get contents of a file on a server. It works just the way I want **but** *"Visual Leak Detector"* points out there is a memory leak on line `closeSocket(...)`.

Code below:

```
string executeUrl(const char *url)
{
    SOCKET sConnection;
    char szHeader[500];

    sprintf(szHeader, "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n"
    "Host: %s\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Agent\r\n"
    "\r\n", url, HTTPSERVER);

    sConnection = HTTPConnectToServer(HTTPSERVER);
    if (sConnection == 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    send(sConnection, szHeader, strlen(szHeader), 0);
    char reply[1024];
    ZeroMemory(reply, 1024);
    if (recv(sConnection, reply, 1024, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return "";
    }
    string returnString(reply);
    closesocket(sConnection);
    WSACleanup();
    return returnString;
}
```

The data leaked **is** the string `returnString`. So it's either string related or something with `closesocket()`.

I did some reading and I can't figure it out. Apparently strings should take care of themselves and not cause memory leaks, should they?

---

EDIT:

I tried the following code: http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-winsock-basic-http-connection

Even this code produces memory leak for me. I also tested a different application (Deleaker) and it also told me there is the same memory leak.

---

EDIT2:

Just found out its not the only time string leaks memory. This piece of code is a problem too:

```
urlString = (string)"http://someurl" + std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(pcName) + (string)"somefile.php";
```

The leaked data is exacly what "urlString" holds. Im completely confused.

Comment: Indeed, string should not leak. So my money is on either closesocket or a bug in the leak detector.

Comment: And yet, the "data" block in VLD contains  EXACTLY what is in "returnString". I made sure by altering it from "reply".

Comment: tried "EDIT", with Visual Studio Express 2013 and Visual Leak Detector 2.3, "No memory leaks detected." . Tried this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) with little modification to create string based on buffer received - "No memory leaks detected."

Comment: Im clueless... maybe something on my PC is bugged.

Comment: Late to the party, but I'm having problems where wstring_convert is leaking  like a seive! But only in Release x64 builds, fine in 32 bit and Debug. Starting to think it's a bug in the MS implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect some undefined behavior. You've read 1024 characters to reply. Then you use constructor that expects null-terminated character sequence. How can you be sure that reply is null-terminated character sequence?

As a quick test try to read 1023 characters instead of 1024, here:

```
if (recv(sConnection, reply, 1023, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

Comment: Tried it ,same memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

When you are reading from a socket you shouldn't assume you have received all your data in one single read.

In this case, the server might have sent more than 1024 bytes and you read exactly 1024. What can happen here is that your buffer will not be NULL-terminated and you try initializing a string with it and without giving it the proper length. Afaik this is undefined behavior, so it's the first thing you may want to fix. Also, you should read all the data sent by the server.

```
char reply[1025];
ZeroMemory(reply, 1025);
string returnString;
int val = 0;
do 
{
    val = recv(sConnection, reply, 1024, 0);
    if (val == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // Treat errors
    }
    strcat (returnString, reply);
    ZeroMemory(reply, 1025);
}
while (val == 1024);
```

**Edit**: This code is wrong. Without having a pre-exchange of messages with the server, it's really hard to tell how many bytes or what contents a message should have. In the case of this code, if the server sends exactly 1024 bytes, then `recv` will be blocked on the next iteration because there will be nothing to read.
Network protocols establish these basic communication rules. For instance, the http protocol states that the first part of the message is composed of headers, each header is ended with a CRLF pair and the end of the header is marked by 2 CRLF pairs. In order for my code to be correct I would have to parse headers and extract Content-Length value and then read the message body until I get to the specified length.

Comment: What if I dont care about anything after first 1024 bytes? Can I read first 1024 bytes and return what was received as a string without memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

This code contains a potential buffer overflow, you should use the string constructor:

```
string returnString(reply, 1024);
```

The constructor you're using assumes it's being passed a null terminated string, which may not be the case depending on the results of recv().

Edit: What is the return value of closesocket? Are you sure the socket is actually being closed before your program terminates? What happens if you wait for a few seconds between the closesocket call and ending your function?

Comment: Doesnt fix memory leak problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to follow some sample code from MSDN, ie.:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

or at least try running this sample to check if it also generates leaks fro you.

I see you are missing [shutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx) call, whether it might cause leaks - I am not sure, from its doc you can read:

> To assure that all data is sent and received on a connected socket before it is closed, an application should use shutdown to close connection before calling closesocket.

btw. when using Win API always check all error codes that might be returned from api functions.

Comment: Tried adding shutdown call but it changes nothing. Ill try to msdn example in a while.